# fgets() function atomatically breaking line when string is printed

Tags: c, line-breaks, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main () {
    char str[5];
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    printf("%s.", str);
}
```

I wrote this simple code in C, and I'm trying to print a string and a dot in a single line, but whenever I enter a string with 3 or less characters, the output has a line break after the string.

Input:

```
abc
```

Output:

```
abc
.
```

If I enter something with exactly 4 characters, the output is as I want, without the line break.

I've tried using the gets() and scanf() functions and they worked well, but I cannot use them.

Does someone know why it happens and a solution?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `fgets`? If yes, read again **carefully**. If not: read carefully.

Comment: [Advice on removing the newline that `fgets` puts in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/3386109)

Comment: "If I enter something with exactly 4 characters, the output is as I want" --> and the `'\n'` is waiting to be read by the _next_ `fgets()` call.  But the program ends first,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `fgets()` reads the newline `char`. You need to take out the newline character which is getting appended in you `char` array.

After
`fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);`
You can write below line to get rid of that newline character

`str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';`
or alternatively you can do like,

```
char * p=NULL;
p= strchr(str,'\n');
if(p!=NULL)
{
 *p='\0';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The explanation to this issue is in the [documentation of `fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

> Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case `str` will contain that newline character.

That is precisely what happens in your case: `str` contains the input string `"abc"` followed by `'\n'`, which gets printed between `"abc"` and dot `'.'`.